# dependent question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, experimental-physics

I compare the of a plane with velocity. independent is the  because this is what is changing. However, not sure about dependent because I want velocity but am measuring the displacement and time taken using the and then later, using this to calculate velocity. Does this mean that is the time or displacement or is it velocity?

Comment: If you attached a drawing, one could better understand the setup. Although it may not be crucial here....

Answer (score 1):

I think the dependent variable is **acceleration**, not velocity. The acceleration should be constant for each angle $\theta$ of inclination, whereas the velocity varies as the truck rolls down the incline at one angle.

The purpose of the experiment is probably to show that acceleration down the plane is proportional to $\sin\theta$. If so your independent variable should be $\sin\theta$ and your dependent variable should be acceleration $a$ (or better still, $a/g$ which does not depend on the units used). A graph of $a/g$ vs $\sin\theta$ should be a straight line, whereas with $\theta$ as independent variable you will not get a straight line.

So for each 'run' of the experiment you need to obtain acceleration $a$ from the ticker tape. How to do this is explained on the [IoP Practical Physics website](http://practicalphysics.org/finding-average-acceleration-ticker-timer.html).

Comment: Good point, this answer gets to the meat of it better than mine.  There's a chance you'll get velocity as a result if your experiment involves kinetic friction equally opposing gravity, but this is rare and would be very hard to set up for multiple angles.

Answer (score 0):

You are measuring velocity as your dependent variable.

The ticker doesn't just measure displacement.  It is measuring the displacement over a set period of time.  Although you may have to do some math to determine it, your experiment is concerned with velocity and the measurements you took reflect that.

If for example your displacement or time were fixed, you could say your dependent variable is the other one.

At the end of the day it has to do with what you want to determine, and perhaps how you determine it.  Also, if you're a student I'd suggest confirming this with your instructor, as they may have their own standards.